# Replacing a div on hover (just CSS)

Tags: html, css, hover

The div that appears when hovered on is offset and won't fill itself in the div it's in. How do you make it take up the position of its parent?

```css
h1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
}

h2 {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}

h1:hover #h2 {
  display: block;
}

h1:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div id="h2">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the hovered div fill its parent div, you can add the following CSS properties to the h2 selector:

```css
h2 {
    display: none;
    height: 100%; /* set the height to 100% of its parent */
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* position it at the top of the parent */
    left: 0; /* position it at the left of the parent */
}
```

Here's the updated code with the modifications:

```css
h1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
}

h2 {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  /* set the height to 100% of its parent */
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* position it at the top of the parent */
  left: 0;
  /* position it at the left of the parent */
}

h1:hover #h2 {
  display: block;
}

h1:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div id="h2">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

With these changes, the h2 div will take up the entire space of its parent div when it is hovered over.

Comment: as you see from the snippet, it does not work. The issue is that block-level element heights are by default `fit-content`. that means, that the height is undefined but will be calculated to fit the content. `height: 100%` means as you correctly stated, 100% of the parent's height. `100%` of undefined is still undefined!